# How do I count how many emails each customer has received when there are multiple emails to count?

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

I am looking to count the number of emails each customer has received however am having trouble as there is more than one customer in the table that needs counting meaning a simple where clause isn't enough.

Here is an example of the Data:

| CustomerID | EmailName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | EmailA |
| 1 | EmailB |
| 2 | EmailA |
| 2 | EmailB |
| 2 | EmailC |
| 3 | EmailA |
| 3 | EmailB |

I am able to count for a specific customer by using a where clause:

`WHERE CustomerID = "1"`

Which will return:

| CustomerID | NumberOfEmailsSent |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |

The issue I am having is I would like to get the following result:

| CustomerID | NumberOfEmailsSent |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 |

The data set I am working with has thousands of email addresses so querying each email address separately is an unrealistic solution.

Comment: . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.  But I think you are just looking for `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you just need a `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT CustomerID, COUNT(EmailName) as 'NumberOfEmailsSent'
FROM tbl
GROUP BY CustomerID
```

Output check here on [DB<>FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=45854ef62c41baa72a8782b2dda975fa)

Answer (score 2):

That is what [`GROUP BY`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) is for.

```
SELECT CustomerID, COUNT(EmailName)
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY CustomerID
```